# is.numeric() or is.digit() not removing non-number elements in a list

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

```
word_line_dict={'abc': ['av', '202', '4140'], 'rcd': ['j00001', '42000', 'j400', '1mm', '440', '1adcmm', '1cmm'], 'lac': ['46', '62', 'm111cmm', '485', 'm111', 't0ta1', 'cmm'], 'halo': ['175', '1355', 'gnt10', '1380', 'gmb10'], 'asd': ['440', '1adcmm', '225000', '1cmm', 'c0unt']}

for keys in word_line_dict:
  for val in word_line_dict[keys]:
    if val.isnumeric() != True:
      word_line_dict[keys].remove(val)

print(word_line_dict)
```

the output of this code is:

```
{'abc': ['202', '4140'], 'rcd': ['42000', '1mm', '440', '1cmm'], 'lac': ['46', '62', '485', 't0ta1'], 'halo': ['175', '1355', '1380'], 'asd': ['440', '225000', 'c0unt']}
```

i just cannot get why this code is not removing the words like 1mm,1cmm,t0tal,c0unt
but running this same code again on the output list removes all these words,
my question is why is it not doing it in the first one only?

what i tried:

```
for keys in word_line_dict:
  temp_list=word_line_dict[keys]
    for val in temp_list:
      if not val.isnumeric():
        word_line_dict[keys].remove(val)
```

Comment: FWIW, `!= True` should basically never be used, use `if not val.isnumeric()`.

Comment: @deceze i took a look at the question where it was specified that editing a list while traversing is not a good idea, but i created a duplicate list and still the thing follow, i also edited the question to what i tried.

Comment: It’s still the same list, just assigned to a different name. You didn’t copy the list at all.

Comment: @deceze thanks a lot, that worked and got to know about lists a bit more.